# how to acess an instance of a component (A broadcastreceiver) declared in the manifest

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, instance

I would like to access a Broadcast Receiver declared in the manifest to be able to register it for some intent which requires explicit registration (using `registerReceiver()`) like `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED`. How can I do that?

TIA

Comment: Use the constructor (e.g., `new YourBroadcastReceiver()` in Java).

Comment: Thanks, I might be wrong but this will create another instance of the BroadcastReceiver , what I would like is to register the instance created by the App from the manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I would like is to register the instance created by the App from the manifest

A manifest-registered receiver is only created when a matching broadcast is sent, and it lives long enough for a single `onReceive()` call. So, there is "the instance created by the App from the manifest" that you can obtain at other times. You need to create your own instance to use with `registerReceiver()`.

Comment: I see so there is no way to add  registration for an intent which is an intent that could not be registered from the manifest in order that the manifest-register receiver will be created on a matching broadcast and one need a receiver created by the app for this purpose. Do you know the reason why android has been designed in order that  some intent like Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED cannot be registered inside the manifest ?

Comment: @Leadev: [This blog post of mine](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/04/11/android-o-implicit-broadcast-ban.html) from 2017 covers the rationale.

Comment: Thanks I understand it better and thank you for the answer indeed